# How do I read the console output from a SHELLEXECUTEINFO object?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I'm executing a C# console app via Visual C++ using a `SHELLEXECUTEINFO` object.  How do I read the console output of my C# console app in my Visual C++ app?

Here is my WORKING code thus far:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = { 0 };
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = "myapp.exe";        
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "";
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't read the output of a spawned process when using `ShellExecute/Ex()`.  You need to use [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) instead. It has a `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag for redirecting the spawned process's `STDIN`/`STDOUT`/STDERR` using pipe(s) that you provide.  See [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) on MSDN for an example.